# For no gap audio concat in FFMPEG, which format to use?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

It's my understanding that FFMPEG will add gaps in between concatenated audio because of so called priming samples that are needed to fill in empty buffers (I think).
Is there an audio format that will do away with this gap?
I'm recording WAV files and the concat command below will add a small gap between the output files. My assumption was that WAV, because it contains PCM data, would not cause the gap.

```
 "-i ${audioFile1} -i ${audioFile2} -filter_complex 'concat=n=2:v=0:a=1[a]' -map '[a]'  $outPath";
```

Comment: The concat filter won't create a gap, even with MDCT codec (AAC, MP3) as long as the surplus samples are marked. With PCM, those gaps may exist in the inputs. Check in an audio editor.

Comment: I've checked in an editor: https://imgur.com/a/QNKtCn5
You can see the small silent gap. I will try to test this with some different files and on a different system as well.

Comment: Check the inputs individually at the relevant ends.